# Save phpgraphlib graph as image

Tags: php, phpgraphlib

My code generates graph from SQL and I am using phpgraphlib for generating the graph. Is there a way to save this graph as a image to a specific location on a server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used it, but [looking at the documentation](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/documentation/function-reference#constructor):

> **Constructor**
>
> `PHPGraphLib ( int $width, int $height, [string $filename] )`
>
> ...
>
> If you
>   specify the optional filename argument, PHPGraphLib will not display
>   to the screen, but instead create a .png file in the same directory as
>   the script where PHPGraphLib is being called.

So, create your graph with the relevant `$filename` in the constructor and it should save there when you call `->createGraph()`.

Comment: Thanks Hamish, you are a saver :)